# Calling an API which implements policy based authorisation using a custom connector in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-logic-apps, role-base-authorization

I have a .NET Core Web API which implements Policy based authorisation and it is hosted on premises. In Azure, I have created a custom connector which talks to the API using an on premises gateway. My problem is, when I am using this custom connector in a Logic App, it fails with error 401 (Unauthorized error) due to the policy based authorisation implemented in the API.

My question is how do I get this to work? is there a way to pass credentials so that my API would understand it's me who is calling it through the custom connector? Or do I need to implement OAuth in my API? 
Hoping to get some advice on this, as I couldn't find any online article related to this.

Thank you.

Comment: How is the web api invoked in the normal world without the logic apps? What are the steps?

Comment: Is that you use Azure AD role base authorization?